# how require ruby class in a namespace

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a class inside a module

```
#lib/app/models/foo.rb
module App::Models
  class Foo
    def bar
      true
    end
  end
end
```

and when i tried to run the spec for it

```
#spec/lib/app/models/foo_spec.rb
require_relative '../../../../lib/app/models/foo'

describe App::Models::Foo do
end
```

i get the follow error:

```
rspec spec/lib/app/models/foo_spec.rb
/Users/frojas/git/tmp/lib/app/models/foo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant App (NameError)
    from /Users/frojas/git/tmp/spec/lib/app/models/foo_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
```

I don't quite understand want i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did you define `App` ? You first need to define it.. Then `module App::Models` this should come..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *have* to define a module before using it:

```
module App
  module Models
    class Foo
      def bar
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way you are defining the `App` module, then the `Models` module and then the `Foo` class properly.

Comment: Thanks! it's not the namespacing i'm using, it was just the first example I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

`module App::Models` means you are defining `Models` module inside `App` module. But Before doing this you need to define the module `App` also. As you didn't do that, so the error *uninitialized constant App (NameError)* it bubbles up.

*First*

```
module App
  # your code
end
```

*Then*

```
module App::Models
  class Foo
    def bar
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Or do as below :

```
module App
  module Models
    class Foo
      def bar
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```